# how to load image from my server side into my android activity using webview?

Tags: android, webview

i have written a program in jsp to display some images on my server side which is working fine, now i want to load that images into my android activity using webview , but my image is not loading

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

String passedData;
TextView txtHeader;
WebView webview;
String url = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.branchwise_timetable);
    passedData = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    txtHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
    txtHeader.setText(passedData);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

}

public void open(View view) {
    url =  
   "http://192.168.120.200:8082/Students_Server/imagetypes_result.jsp? 
    year_branch="+ passedData;
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.loadUrl(url);

}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

this activity is opening up from the activity which has a list and when i click an item on the list , this activity opens up and the String passedData is the passed valued of specific item in the list which i am appending at the end of the url , which makes this activity to load specific image of specific item.
Please need some help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the direct link for the images from your server, then I recommend to you displaying your in `ImageView` and use any of the `Image Lazy Loader` such as [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Dealing with `WebView`s has some problems, but dealing with a direct link uisng `ImageViews` is much easier and reliable.

All you have to do is to follow this [Tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-library-in-android) and just try to send your images direct link to the mobile side using any method such as using `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

For loading multiple images from url you can use webview but if you want to display single image and if you know image url then you can use imageview to download and display.